# Route parameter in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, parameters, laravel-4, routes

Please check my routing about this problem:

```
    Route::any('author/(:id)' , array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@view'));
```

And the controller:

```
    public function view($id){
    return View::make('authors.view')
        ->with('title','Ini Halaman Penulis Berdasarkan Urutan Abjad')
        ->with('author', Author::find($id));
```

view.blade.php:

```
    @extends('layouts.default')

    @section('content')
      <h1>{{ $author->name }}</h1>
      <p>{{ $author->bio }}</p>
      <p>{{ $author->updated_at }}</p>
    @stop
```

I knew if this syntax from the old laravel and i've searched the exact syntax from the newest laravel, but still don't get it.

Comment: Simple - use `{id}` instead of `(:id)` in the route. See [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) for more info.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @alexrussell.

Comment: D'oh, too late :) To be honest I figured it was too small an answer to be an answer but I guess even small answers are valid if they do fully answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your route to

```
Route::any('author/{id}' , array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@view'));
```